# Azure AD B2C login with Microsoft identity provider error: Proof Key for Code Exchange is required for cross-origin authorization code redemption

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, identity-provider

I am getting this error on Azure AD B2C login with Microsoft identity provider:

> AADB2C90273: An invalid response was received : 'Error: invalid_request,Error Description: Proof Key for Code Exchange is required for cross-origin authorization code redemption.'

[image]

I have added web redirect url like this:

[image]

I tried many ways find on google, stack overflow and others, but nothing seems to be working.

Please help me solve this error.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you also include the code you are using to login?

Comment: @Rukmini I tried in Run user flow with https://jwt.ms redirect url, In this also not working

Comment: Can you disbale the implicit flow that is uncheck [**this**](https://i.imgur.com/h2wetSM.png)

Comment: @Rukmini If disable the implicit flow then after login no data coming like: email, etc...

Comment: Please add more context to the question. Which code/request causes the error? In general the error indicates that you are not using the PKCE oauth extension.

Comment: After disabling implicit flow are you getting the tokens?

Comment: @Rukmini No, not getting token

Comment: Can you paste the screenshots for more clarity as I am able to login successfully in my environment.

Comment: @Rukmini after login I got following screen
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CrKRoK9HQ8SqOZ-H94Vy_z4aGprr0FeK/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you try to create new Azure B2C application and check again?

Comment: And did you configure any redirect URL in SPA platform?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65767980/invalid-response-signing-in-via-microsoft-identity-provider-with-azure-ad-b2c

Comment: @Rukmini Right now not configure any redirect URL in SPA. I try with this also but not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257269/discussion-between-rukmini-and-chirag-kothiya).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To configure Microsoft Account as the IDP,** you need to register the application in **Microsoft Entra ID tenant (Azure AD tenant)**:

Add redirect URL as **`https://your-tenant-name.b2clogin.com/your-tenant-name.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authresp`**

[image]

And **supported account types**: Personal Microsoft accounts only:

[image]

Create **Azure AD B2C application** in the **Azure AD B2C tenant** and added redirect URI as **`https://jwt.ms`**

[image]

**Now create the IDP by passing the Azure AD application ID and secret value in the Microsoft Entra ID tenant (Azure AD tenant)**:

[image]

Run user flow by selecting the IDP:

[image]

Select Microsoft Account:

[image]

***The user is now able to sign-in successfully and ID token is generated:***

[image]

**If you want to fetch access tokens along with ID token**, then you need to Expose an API and scope in the Azure AD B2C application:

[image]

Grant API permission for the scope:

[image]

While running the user flow, select **resource as your b2c application** and run:

[image]

Now both **ID and access tokens will be generated** when the user will sign in:

[image]